# PrimeNG size TurboTable to containing Element

Tags: html, css-tables, primeng

What I *want* to do is to have the scrollHeight effectively calculated to take up the available space within a containing div. Unfortunately, scrollHeight, which controls the max-height of the the ui-table-scrollable-body, doesn't allow for the calculation I would need (which is the available height, minus all the header and footer elements. I've worked around this by:

1. Adding SCSS (using:: ng-deep, not sure there's a way around it) to set .ui-table, .ui-table-scrollable-wrapper, and the div immediately following to 100%
2. Creating a service that uses 'element-resize-detector'
3. Watching the various elements of the table through the service
4. Changing the element with ui-table-scrollable-body to be: calc (100% - [I]height_of_the_other_elements_px[/I])

This works as far as the scrolling goes. As I resize the screen, The scrollable body is resized accordingly, and its fairly quick. (I suppose I could forgo the CSS, and target a containing element that is set to some height, and do the calc myself, but then then the style is constantly changing).

However, the table header doesn't respond to the scrollbar appearance/disappearance, so it doesn't know to realign the scrollbar (alignScrollBar() in [table.ts](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts)), and I see no way to trigger that, since the internal component isn't exposed in the Table API. So I may need to duplicate the code. This seems to be related to [Issue 5013](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5013), though.

All this to say: This is an awfully invasive (and complicated) way to do something conceptually simple as "Use the available space for the table, sizing the scroll area accordingly". Is there a simpler way to get the same result with TurboTable? (I posted this to the [PrimeNG Community Forum](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=54475), as well.)